# setting background to contain but has leftover space

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I,ve been working on some media responsive design for my portfolio and it's coming along great but i have a problem. the image i have on my home screen and tablet display(resize smaller to see tablet display) are both set to background-size contain. i did this because i didn't like my image being stretched to fit the div, but now i have a giant gap on my page at the bottom.(on the smaller tablet screen and home desktop screen). is there a way i can keep the image the way it is and remove the bottom gap?

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="home.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<title>Tavyon Richardson</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" >
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
                <ul class="icon">
                    <li class="h1">Tavyon <span class="name">Richardson</span></li>
                <li class="list">TavyonRichardson@yahoo.com<i class="material-icons">mail_outline</i></li>
                <li class="list">989-285-5133<i class="material-icons">call</i></li>
                <li class="list">Alma, Michigan<i class="material-icons">location_on</i></li>
            </ul>
            </header>
       <div id="background">
           <p class="web"><span>Hey!</span>Welcome to my webiste. Here, you can see everything from my life story, to my my recent projects and resume.</p>
        <nav id="navbar">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="stretch"><a href="">About me</a></li>
                <li class="stretch"><a href="">Courses</a></li>
               <li class="stretch"><a href="http://tavyonrichardson.com/projects.html">Projects</a></li>
                <li class="stretch"><a href="http://tavyonrichardson.com/nms_114/blog">Blog</a></li>
               <li class="stretch"><a href="">Resume</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="mback">
        <p class="mobile"><span>Hey!</span>Welcome to my webiste. Here, you can see everything from my life story, to my my recent projects and resume.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Overlock');

*{
margin: 0 ;
padding: 0;


}
#wrapper {
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;

}

#background {
display: block;
background-image: url(images/Untitled-1.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain; 
overflow: auto;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;

}

header{
background: rgb(115, 78, 116);
width: auto;
padding: 1%;
}
.web{
width: 20%;
font-size: 20px;
color: antiquewhite;
padding: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
position:absolute;
margin-left: 50%;
font-family: 'Overlock', sans-serif;
font-style: normal;
margin-top: 15%;
}

.mobile, .mback{
display: none;

}

}
.icon{
list-style-type: none;
display: inline;



}
.list{
display: inline-block;
font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
margin-right: 1%;

}

i{
display: inline;
}

body {
background-color: black;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

footer{
color: antiquewhite;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}


.h1{font-family:'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
color: floralwhite;
font-size: 300%;
display: inline;
padding-right: 300px;
font-weight: bolder;
}

.name{font-family:'Lobster', sans-serif;
color: floralwhite;
display: inline;
font-weight: normal;
}
nav {
float: right;
}
.stretch{
list-style-type: none;
padding: 20px;
margin: 20px 0px;
border-radius: 50px 0px 0px 50px;
width: 250px;
height: 50px;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
font-size: 150%;
font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
background-color: rgb(40, 31, 17);
position: relative;
-webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
-webkit-transition-property: color;
transition-property: color;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.stretch:before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
border-radius: 50px 0px 0px 50px;
background:rgb(91, 56, 29);
-webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
transform: scaleX(0);
-webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
transform-origin: 100% 50%;
-webkit-transition-property: transform;
transition-property: transform;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
transition-duration: 0.5s;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
a:link,a:visited, a:hover,a:active  {
text-decoration: none;
color: antiquewhite;   
}

.stretch:hover:before, .stretch:focus:before, .stretch:active:before {
-webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
transform: scaleX(1);
-webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.52, 1.64, 0.37, 0.66);
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.52, 1.64, 0.37, 0.66);
}


/* ----------- Galaxy S4 ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media screen 
and (device-width: 320px) 
and (device-height: 640px) 
{









}

      /* ----------- tablet ----------- */
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {

/*changing nav to horizontal postion*/
nav, nav ul, nav li, nav a{
display: inline;
float: none;
width: 100%;
margin: 0px auto;
padding: 0px;
text-align: center;
}

.stretch{
display: inline-block;
list-style-type: none;
padding: 10px;
margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
width:auto;
height: auto;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
font-size: 100%;
font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
background-color: rgb(40, 31, 17);
position: static;
/*    removing nav animation*/
-webkit-transform: none;
transform:none;
-webkit-transform-origin:none;
transform-origin:none;
-webkit-transition-property: none;
transition-property: none;
-webkit-transition-duration: none;
transition-duration: none;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: none;
transition-timing-function: none;
}
.stretch:hover:before, .stretch:focus:before, .stretch:active:before {
-webkit-transform: none;
transform: none;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: none;
transition-timing-function: none;
}
.stretch:before {
content: "";
position: none;
z-index: none;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
border-radius: 50px 0px 0px 50px;
background:none;
-webkit-transform: scaleX (none);
transform: scaleX(none);
-webkit-transform-origin: none;
transform-origin: none;
-webkit-transition-property: none;
transition-property: none;
-webkit-transition-duration:none;
transition-duration: none;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: none;
transition-timing-function: none;
}

/*    adding nav background back instead of image*/
#background {
background-color: rgb(40, 31, 17);
width: 100%;
background-image: none;
}
/*trying to get the background to display correctly*/
body {
background-color: black;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.mback{
border: 2px solid red;
display: block;
background-image: url(images/Untitled-1.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
width: auto;
height: 900px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
}


/*moving the paragraph to the left since image will not display*/
    .web{
display: none;        
}

.mobile {
text-align: right;
display: block;
width: 20%;
font-size: 20px;
color: antiquewhite;
padding: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
font-family: 'Overlock', sans-serif;
font-style: normal;
position: static;
float: right;
}







}
```

Comment: You need to add a drawing showing how you want it to look, as now it is difficult to understand what you mean. Can't see now image either

Comment: it already is how i want it to look , theres just a giant gap at the bottom of the code if you run the snippet.

Comment: As I said, don't understand what gap you talk about, so if you provide a drawing showing it, we might be able to help

Comment: oh i get it, you can't see the image there for you dont see the gap. for some reason the browser isn't loading the image even though it loads on my screen.